# "detail":"ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to insert a dynamic value into a procedure and everytime I run it, I get this error.

> "detail":"ORA-02291: integrity constraint (VIEW.AA_DEFAULT_APP_LIST_FK_AA_APP) violated - parent key not found

This is my procedure.

```
router.put('/update-applications/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;

    logger.info(pool._logStats());

    logger.info("Begin: " + (new Date().toString()));


    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        logger.info("Begin Connection: " + (new Date().toString()));
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        var bindvars = {
            appId: '\'' + data.appId + '\'',
            error: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 4000}
        };

        logger.info("Bindvars Set: " + (new Date().toString()));

        logger.info('***********************************');
        logger.info('Add Application - PUT');
        logger.info('App ID: ', bindvars.appId);
        logger.info('***********************************');

        logger.info("Begin execute: " + (new Date().toString()));

        connection.execute(
            "BEGIN local.pkg_app.p_ins_app_id(:appId, :error); END;",
            bindvars,
            function (err, result) {
                logger.info(JSON.parse(result.outBinds.error));
                logger.info("End execute: " + (new Date().toString()));
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err.message);
                    doRelease(connection);
                    return;
                }

                logger.info("Send JSON: " + (new Date().toString()));
                res.json(JSON.parse(result.outBinds.error));
                logger.info("JSON Sent: " + (new Date().toString()));

                doRelease(connection);
            });
    });
});
```

I tried this code in SQL Developer and it works fine for me..

```
declare
v_app_id varchar2(10) := 'A123456';
o_error                    VARCHAR2(100) := 'None';
Begin
dbms_output.put_line('START');
local.PKG_APP.p_ins_app_id(v_app_id,o_error );
dbms_output.put_line('END');
dbms_output.put_line(o_error);
end;
```

Please help.

Comment: I haven't used node.js much, but I'm pretty sure the extra quotes around your `appId` bind variable are the problem.

Comment: But I should wrap it in quotes and pass it in as a variable. I'll try without the quotes and reply back.

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. Now trying to remove one and getting ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number\n"

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by removing quotes.